# Duplicate list elements which based on predicate

Tags: list, scala, duplicates

I would like to duplicate even/odd elements in a list.

```
def even(number: Int): Boolean = {
    if(number%2 == 0) true
    else false
}
```

I tried something weird cause i have no idea how should I do that exactly.

```
scala> var x = List(1, 2, 3)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> x.map(el => if(even(el)) el::x)
res143: List[Any] = List((), List(2, 1, 2, 3), ())
```

This is not what I expected. I'd like to return only one list with all elements where odd/even are duplicated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *"odd/even are duplicated"* ?

Comment: for ```List(1, 2, 3)``` program should return ```List(1, 2, 2, 3)``` cause 2 is even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatMap to return a list per element, either containing just the element itself if the predicate doesn't match, or a list with the element duplicated if it does:

```
def even(n : Int) : Boolean = n%2 == 0
val l = List(1,2,3)
l.flatMap(n => if(even(n)) List(n,n) else List(n)) // -> List(1, 2, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the first collection for even numbers, and than concat with the original list:

```
scala> var l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.filter(_ % 2 == 0) ++ l
res14: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 2, 3)
```

If you want the `List[Int]` sorted, you can apply that after the concatenation:

```
scala> l.filter(_ % 2 == 0) ++ l sorted
res15: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 2, 3)
```

This saves you the allocation of a new `List[Int]` for every match of `even`. You filter only the elements you need, creating one `List[Int]`, and then concatenating it with the original.